# How can Test Web Component inside React Component

Tags: reactjs, web-component

How can I test a web component inside a component in React?

```
import React from 'react';

function Form() {
  return <div>
    <label htmlFor="">Name:</label>
    <custom-input
      name='name'
      data-testid='name-input'
      onChange={(e) => handleName(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
}

export default Form;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can test it the same way you would test any HTML element.

Comment: @G.Tranter, this not a simple test.. It's Very different

Comment: Please explain what you need to test.

Comment: I need to test custom-input, that no a component. Is a Tag Customized

Comment: Tests for custom-input belong with that component. The tests for your react component should only cover public features of custom-input that you are using, so it's much like any HTML element.